# Mongoose Schema for SMS Log

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose-schema

My app sends SMS to students and I need to save sms history
I want to find both

1. Student List by SMS Id
2. List of sms sent to student

Which is Better Approach:
 1. SMS History Schema

```
{
date: String,
smsCount: Number,
studentIds: Array[Number]   
}
```

2. SMS id in student Column

```
{
name: String;
rollNo: Number;
smsIds: Array[Number]
}
```

3. Seperate Log Schema

```
 {
   smsId: Number,
   userId: Number,
   date:   Date
 }
```

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine your 1st and 2nd schema to achieve the desired result. In SMS schema you need to embed a list of Student ID and in Student schema, you need to add a list of SMS Id. For the better understanding of N: M relation in mongo please refer [this](http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/schemabasics/).

Comment: Is this best way?any other approach other than this?

Comment: Yes as you need to maintain N: M relationship this approach is best. For query in both the collection, you have some option like join on application level or lookup depending on your business requirements.